# sending 16 bit command via SPI to a NCV7719 (half bridge)

Tags: spi, h-bridge

I am trying to send a 16 bit command to a Half bridge (data sheet here http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7719-D.PDF) to open one of the transistors to turn on an LED. at the bottom of the data sheet (page 13) it says which bit needs to be a 1 or a 0 in order to activate the half bridge. This is the code I wrote but it isn't work (I'm assuming I'm not sending the 16 bits properly). Can someone figure out why this isn't working?

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  SPI.begin();

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  //pulling pin low to decide to write to device 
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);

  //function to send information
  //truning on half bridge 4 
  SPI.transfer(0000010000000000);
delay(500);
  //finish transfering data
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);

}
```

Comment: FYI, `0000010000000000` is not a binary constant in C++ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

SPI writes in 8-bit bytes. So the writes need to look like this:

```c++
  SPI.transfer(0b00000100);  // first byte
  SPI.transfer(0b00000000);  // second byte
```

Possibly in the other order depending on which byte the device expects first.